# SaltStack: How to boostrap machines launched by salt-cloud which already has the salt-minion software installed?

Tags: salt-stack

In an effort to speed up the boot up and configuration of a newly launched machine via salt-cloud (on EC2 in my case but this is applicable to all cloud providers), I've installed the salt-minion software in the AMI. After launching via salt-cloud, I only want the deployment phase to accept the minion on the salt master (and set some grains) without trying to do a fresh installation of salt-minion. Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in the '--no-deploy' option to Salt Cloud so that it doesn't try to install the minion again.

As far as automatically accepting keys, you may want to take a look at the Salt formula:

https://github.com/saltstack-formulas/ec2-autoscale-reactor